# Ball oblique impact physic in Java?

Tags: java, collision-detection, physics

[image: Ball collision]

I know **Q3 + Q4 = 90**

I searched internet and many physic topics, but not found how to calculate this values in Java?

(I found V3 and V4 but not found Q3 and Q4)

So how can i calculate **V3**, **V4**, **Q3**, **Q4** values after the collision in Java?

Comment: It seems like you just want to simulate [elastic collision](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/when-worlds-collide-simulating-circle-circle-collisions--gamedev-769)

Comment: @newton1212 no, elastic collision is "center collision", so the balls are always collision the center line. But i want angled collision like billiards phsics. In your tuts+ link the collisions is not realistic If you look carefully. The balls is always behaving as center collision. So my (V1) direction is not intersect with (V2)'s center, because they are collision with angle

Comment: There's no such thing as spheres colliding anywhere other than their centers.  The only thing that can change is the angle of the line from center to center.

Comment: Also, is this a homework problem?  That's the only reason I can think of why you would state a specific sum of Q3 and Q4, but demand their values.  Their value is whatever it is; aren't you interested in the general solution?

Comment: I am not student, I am game programmer i just can't calculate the values for make "angled collision billiard" game

Answer (score 1):

So, you want the angle of velocity relative to the x-axis? That'd be `atan(V3.y/V3.x)` and `atan(V4.y/V4.x)` for **Q3** and **Q4**, respectively.

Though, since the balls are almost aligned along the y-axis in relation to each other, it looks like maybe you're looking for the angle of V3/V4 relative to the surface at the point of impact, even when that doesn't line up with the x-axis.

In that case, you need the **normal** of impact (most collision functions will give you this as some of the output, but it's easy for spheres/circles anyway -- just normalise `ball1.xy - ball2.xy`). Anyway, you can use that normal and **V3** to calculate **Q3** like so:

`acos(DotProduct(normal, V3.Normalised()))`.

It'll vary a little depending on what libraries you're using, but basically: the dot product of two normalised vectors (that is, vectors with a magnitude of **1**) will be the cos of the angle between the vectors. Apply the inverse cos function (**acos**) and you get the angle between them.

For **Q4**, replace "V3" with "V4".

Answer (score 1):

It's much simpler than you think:

Just use the "relative velocity" to calculate the impulse

```
relVel = vB - vA;
```

Then, use it to project against the normal to find the impulse.

```
normal = (posB-posA) / Length(posB-posA);

coefficient_of_restituition = 0; // (100% energy lost)
coefficient_of_restituition = 1; // (0% energy lost)

impulse = -(1 + coefficient_of_restituition) * dot(relVel, Normal) / (invMassA + invMassB);
```

Answer (score -1):

maby this can help you 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution
there is a break down of the entire problem

Comment: How can i calculate Q3, Q4?